# Put all the (foreach) values in one array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get all the values from the foreach key as value in one array. Currently I am doing like this.

```
foreach($key as $value){
$data = "<div>{$value->names}</div><div>{$value->firstlatter}</div>";
$json = array('values' => $data);
print_r($json);
}
```

so it returns in values.

```
    array([values] => <div>apple</div><div>a</div>)
    array([values] => <div>banana</div><div>b</div>)
    array([values] => <div>mango</div><div>m</div>)
    array([values] => <div>orange</div><div>o</div>)
```

but i want to get all the values in one array . below is the example which i want to get.

```
array([values] => <div>apple</div><div>a</div><div>banana</div><div>b</div><div>mango</div><div>m</div><div>orange</div><div>o</div>);
```

Comment: Can you please tell my why you accepted @MarcoMura's answer, why is his one better then mine? He posted his answer after mine and it's similar to mine, so he also could copied it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can loop and add element to a string like:

```
$data = "";
foreach($key as $value){
   $data .= "<div>{$value->names}</div><div>{$value->firstlatter}</div>";
}

$json = array('values' => $data);
```

And put all that string after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($key as $value){
  $data = "<div>{$value->names}</div><div>{$value->firstlatter}</div>";
  $json[] = array('values' => $data);
}
```

Use the `$json[]` to add the array with the data in it to add it to another array.

Comment: This is not what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $data = "";

    foreach($key as $value) {
        $data .= "<div>{$value->names}</div><div>{$value->firstlatter}</div>";
    }

    $json = array('values' => $data);
    print_r($json);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a closure:

```
$json['values'] = array_reduce(
    $key,
    function ($a, $b) {
        return $a . "<div>{$b->names}</div><div>{$b->firstlatter}</div>";
    }
);
```